# How can you make a gradient background without images?

Tags: html, xhtml, cross-browser, css

Like this. in general i will make 1 px wide image of this then will `repeat-x`.

but is it possible to make same type of background with CSS3 , if yes then tell me how tp make same of this.

[alt text http://shup.com/Shup/367066/110519102044-My-Desktop.png](http://shup.com/Shup/367066/110519102044-My-Desktop.png)

with all browser compatibility IE 8, 7, 6 , FF , Chrome, Safari, iphone.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Pretty much all of the browsers support gradients. Here's the CSS you need:

```
.gradient{
    /* For any browser that can't create a gradient  */
    background-color: #EFEFEF;
    /*//mozilla*/
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #efefef, #FFF);
    /* Chrome/Safari     */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#EFEFEF), to(#FFF));
    /*IE 6/7 */ filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Gradient(GradientType=0, StartColorStr='#EFEFEF',EndColorStr='#FFF');
    /*IE 8 */
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#EFEFEF, endColorstr=#FFF)";
}
```

Comment: Check your colors. This is a very delicate one from light grey to white. And Opera doesn't believe in gradients at all.

Comment: ok but why it's not working http://jsbin.com/iquje4/2 please can you edit this to make same like gradient image in my question

Comment: Yes, it was my crappy monitor... :D +1 for you.

Answer (score 3):

Try some of the CSS gradient generators that you can find with a Google search, such as:
http://gradients.glrzad.com/

or

http://www.designdetector.com/demos/css-gradients-demo-1.php

Also, take a look at Webkit's gradient tutorial:
http://webkit.org/blog/175/introducing-css-gradients/

And Firefox:
http://hacks.mozilla.org/2009/11/css-gradients-firefox-36/

Now - that in mind:
This is new stuff -- CSS3, which isn't finalized yet.  Browser support for CSS3 stuff is very cutting edge.  You're not going to get cross browser support for the browsers you've listed.  Latest Webkit (Safari, Google Chrome) and Firefox are your best bets. IE supports filters. Opera doesn't support any kind of gradients though.

Comment: @metal-gear-solid - Yes, but you will have to have a backup gradient image for IE6 and maybe 7, and load those images if CSS doesnt work.

Comment: IE does gradients, they just use "filter."

Comment: @Aaron Harun - Does IE filter works if javascript is disabled

Comment: @Metal, they should. They are pure CSS. Weird CSS, but still CSS.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms532847%28VS.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I think IE 6 and 7 may not support CSS3 gradient.
Even though, you can get the CSS code from this site
http://gradients.glrzad.com/